# MySQL Syntax Error when Select Count into inout Variable

Tags: mysql

Here is the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CountOrderByStatus(
IN orderStatus VARCHAR(25),
OUT total INT)
BEGIN
SELECT count(orderNumber)
INTO total
FROM orders
WHERE status = orderStatus;
END
```

When I try to execute this, i get the following error:

> Error SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 8

I was googling for a while, but I can't find any information about this problem. Many sources does not refer such type of code as invalid. For example, fragment above  found at [**this**](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx) site.

Any ideas, why everybody is saying, that is normal, but MySQL produces such strange error?

P.S.: MySQL Server 5.6 at Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Was forget to add DELIMITER. It must look:

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE CountOrderByStatus(
    IN orderStatus VARCHAR(25),
    OUT total INT)
    BEGIN
    SELECT count(orderNumber)
    INTO total
    FROM orders
    WHERE status = orderStatus;
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```